# How to accept comma-separated values in regex pattern Angular

Tags: regex, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `textarea` component which accepts these regex patterns:

```
UserExamble.com,user@,@examble.com,@examble.com
```

Now i have implemented all above patterns but in textarea, there are supposed to be multiple values seperated by comma, for ex. `UserExamble.com,user@`  or `UserExamble.com,user@,@examble.com,@examble.com`. This is what i am not able to implement, how can i do this?

Below is my code:

```
this.userPolicyForm = this.fb.group({
  senderRadioBtn: ['Any'],
  senderEmailaddress: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(ValidationPatternConfig.userPolicyEmailAddressPattern)]]
});
```

and

`ValidationPatternConfig.userPolicyEmailAddressPattern`=

```
"^(([^<>()\\[\\]\\\\,;:\\s@\\\"]+(\\.[^<>()\\[\\]\\\\,;:\\s@\\\"]+)*)|(\\\".+\\\")){1,64}@(\\[ipv6:){1}(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))\\]$"
```

+`"|"`+

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9+.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]{1,64}@\\[(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\]$"
```

+`"|"`+

```
"^(([^<>()\\[\\]\\\\,;:\\s@\\\"]+(\\.[^<>()\\[\\]\\\\,;:\\s@\\\"]+)*)|(\\\".+\\\")){1,64}@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$"
```

+`"|"`+

```
"^$|^((?!\\.)[\\w-_.]*[^.])(@\\w+)(\\.\\w+(\\.\\w+)?[^.\\W])$"
```

+`"|"`+

```
"^([a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+\\/=?^_`\\{|\\}~\\-.]*[^@,\\]\\[<>:;\"()])@$"
```

+`"|"`+

```
"^@(([a-zA-Z0-9]*([-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]*([-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]))$"
```

I am using `reactive forms` in `angular`.

I have seen few stackoverflow answers, but none of them work. I am new to angular and regex, need help.

Comment: Can you show what you have implemented?

Comment: @CinCout okay, I'll update the code

Comment: @CinCout I have updated the code, can you check it now?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to create custom email validator

```
this.userPolicyForm = this.fb.group({
  senderRadioBtn: ['Any'],
  senderEmailaddress: ['', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.validateEmail()]]
});
```

Create a new file for `custom-validator.ts`

```
import { AbstractControl, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class CustomValidators {
  // validating array of emails
  static validateEmail() {
    return (control: FormControl) => {
      const pattern = new RegExp('^([a-z0-9\\+_\\-]+)(\\.[a-z0-9\\+_\\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\\-]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$', 'i');
      let validEmail = true;
      if (control.value !== null) {
        const emails = control.value.replace(/\s/g, '').split(',').filter((mail: any) => mail.trim());
        for (const email of emails) {
          if (email && !pattern.test(email)) {
            validEmail = false;
          }
        }
      }
      return validEmail ? null : { invalid_email: true };
    };
  }
}
```

In `html`, you can add

```
<div *ngIf="userPolicyForm.controls.senderEmailaddress.hasError('invalid_email')">
    Email address must be valid
</div>
```

From this you can validate in reactive form. Also when you are submitting array of emails, you can trim it to send to API.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide on the patterns which you want to pass in your textbox and then create regex in 2 parts, one containing the pattern with a comma at the end and a greedy + and second part with just the pattern

like this:

```
let pattern = "(?:[A-z0-9]+@[A-z]+\.[A-z]{2,6})|(?:[A-z0-9]+@[A-z]+)|(?:@[A-z0-9]+\.[A-z]{2,6})|(?:[A-z0-9]\.[A-z]{2,6})"

var regexPattern = '/(?:' + pattern + '[,])+' + pattern + '/'
var regex = new RegExp(regexPattern)
console.log("UserExamble.com,user@some.com,@examble.com,run.com", regex.test("UserExamble.com,user@some.com,@examble.com,run.com"))
```

you can use this single regex to validate the input.